# com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, cxf

My apache cxf client web service got exception just like below. However, 'XML type name "address"' is the soap:address location of my WSDL. What is the problem?

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "address". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference$Address
        at public com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference$Address com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference.addr
        at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Address
        at private javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Address javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference.address
        at javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference
Two classes have the same XML type name "elements". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference$Elements
        at public com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference$Elements com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference.referenceProperties
        at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Elements
        at private javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Elements javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference.referenceParameters
        at javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference
```

Comment: Share part of your code and the WDSL. But the exception is very clear. Two classes annotated with same name property("address").

Comment: Actually There is no address property. this address is only soap address localtion of the WSDLs. I've solved the problem. When u use spring+jaxws for your server side service and apache+cxf for your another client side service, there will be a conflict for endpoint address property of WSDLs. THUS, i used apache-cxf + spring for both services. Thanks a lot

Comment: Why don't you put that comment of yours as a answer so the question don't stay as unanswered and it may help some else later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is interesting. This is not a full answer, but this might help.

The `com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference.Address` class is not annotated, there's also no `package-info.java`. So the type should be named `address`, without namespace.

The class `javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference.Address` is also not annotated, but there is a `package-info.java`:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace=W3CEndpointReference.NS,
                                     location="http://www.w3.org/2006/03/addressing/ws-addr.xsd")
package javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing;
```

So it should be named `{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing:address`. So theoretically there should be no conflict.

I'd suggest the following:

- Check your classes and packages.

  - Do you have a `package-info.java` in `javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing`?
  - Do you have one in `com.sun.xml.ws.developer`?
- Try updating versions of your libraries. Maybe this was a temporary glitch between versions.

**UPDATE**

I have found exactly the same problem [reported on java.net](https://www.java.net/node/685468). One of the solutions posted there is, basically, "update your versions". Also seems to be relevant to NetBeans somehow.

Comment: i used apache-cxf + spring for both services. and skipped problem using different developing strategy

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered exactly the same issue. **This is not a solution but a workaround**.

First of all, the wsdl based on which I had built my client was an autogenerated wsdl. This type of wsdls usually contain more than one shema, like in my case (4 schemas). I don't say that this is wrong but in my case what I did was to remove the last 3 schemas and move all the elements inside the first one along with what that entails (changes in namespaces etc.). After doing this I built my client again and the error was solved.